# Windows Phone 8: Display on screen softkeyboard after pressing a button on screen in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, search, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am implementing search functionality on a given list,and the requirement is:  right at the moment while search button is pressed the search textbox will be focused and the onscreen softkeyboard will be available. Creating focus is easy but Any idea guys how could display the onscreen keybard?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to control the onscreen keyboard.  I think the only way it is displayed is when the user clicks on control like a textbox